# Finding host on local network using Raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, host

I´m trying to write a python script to find a list of pc's that are connect to my local network using a raspberry pi. But for some reason my code does not work on the Pi while it does work on my windows laptop.

Here is what I have so far

```
`import socket, os

 dic = ("pc1", "pc2", "pc3")
 ips = []
 for i in range(0, len(dic)):
     f = socket.gethostbyname(dic[i])
     ips.append(f)
     print f
```

`
I just get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Thank you in advance for any help that you can give me.

Comment: This looks like your DNS lookup domain is not set up. It is not a programming problem.